# Java 8 Filter+Collect to list NullpointerException

Tags: java, list, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I've been working with stream api for a while but didn't encounter any such case till now. Why is this code throwing a NPE?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MarkupModel m1 = new MarkupModel();
    m1.setOverrideFlag(true);
    MarkupModel m2 = new MarkupModel();
    m1.setOverrideFlag(false);
    List<MarkupModel> markupModelList = new LinkedList<>();
    markupModelList.add(m1);
    markupModelList.add(m2);
    List<MarkupModel> typeAMarkupStream = markupModelList.stream()
        .filter(markupModel -> !markupModel.getOverrideFlag())
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); //NPE thrown here
}
```

Comment: May be a typo, but you are setting the flag only for m1.

Comment: @Eritrean indeed, and the flag is a `Boolean`, so there's a `null` from `m2`.

Comment: @Eritrean You found it. It was a typo. My bad!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would have to filter `null` elements:

```
List<MarkupModel> typeAMarkupStream = markupModelList.stream()
    .filter(markupModel -> markupModel.getOverrideFlag() == null || !markupModel.getOverrideFlag())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: But why? We can very well see that objects aren't null. Isn't that check unnecessary?

Comment: @DurlabhSharma you're right, sorry, it's the `overrideFlag`, that is `null`, because it's an object (and not primitive), this should solve your problem

Comment: It was a typo in my code. It's working fine now. I wasn't setting value for both the objects. So your code also handles the situation but it was a fault with my own code that created this issue.

Comment: @DurlabhSharma that's correct!